# Can `extends` be followed by no values?

Tags: scala

I'm surprised to see that ScalaPB generated code like this:

```
object KinesisMessageType extends {
    @SerialVersionUID(0L)
    case object Empty extends com.example.message.KinesisMessage.KinesisMessageType {
      // ...
    }
}
```

You can write `extends` without specifying anything?  Why does it allow this?  Are there any docs on this syntax?

Comment: interesting `class EmptyClass(val data: String) extends {}` seems equivalent to `class EmptyClass(val data: String){}`. I don't see any issues

Comment: Actually `class CaseClass(x: Int) extends` does not work. Meaning extends seem to take `{}` as parent, as it works with `case class CaseClass(x: Int) extends {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. According to the [syntax specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions):

> The extends clause [...] can be omitted, in which case extends scala.AnyRef is assumed.

Comment: you are saying one can omit `extends` part, but the question is `extends `followed by nothing other than `{}`?

Comment: @prayagupd The "extends clause" in the context of the spec is the template `t` in `... extends t`. @Hamms is correct. Try it: `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify { object A extends { val b = 123 } }`

Comment: @MichaelZajac I understand even if I omit `extends`, everything will extend `scala.AnyRef`but  when you say `t` can be committed in `... extends t` Why `class A(x: Int) extends` is invalid(compiler time) but `class A(x: Int) ` is valid. I'm missing something :)

Comment: @prayagupd But `class A(x: Int) extends {}` is not invalid. You can omit `t`, or you can omit the body `{...}`, but not both. The spec doesn't explicitly say "not both", but the language clearly behaves that way when you try each case.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Thats what I exactly meant to know why `class A(x: Int) extends {}` is valid but not `class A(x: Int) extends` if what you were saying `t` could be omitted in `extends t` were true. (_I'm not saying you are wrong but wanted to be more clear_).

Comment: This does not answer the question (or, it does, but only because of a technicality that doesn't match OP's intent): the extends clause in `class A extends B {}` is `extends B`, which can be omitted to have `class A {}` (no `extends`). That's not what OP is asking, which is really "why does `class A extends {}` work? The extends clause is there, because there is an `extends`. The reason it works is what @tkroman said.

Comment: @MichaelZajac No, this is incorrect. `t` includes the body, so if you omitted it you'd get precisely `class A(x: Int) extends`.

Answer (score 3):

<s>It's actually `A extends <anonymous class>` with the body of `A` omitted. So that's not an `extends` followed by nothing and the body of `A`, but rather `extends { ... }` followed by the empty body of `A`.</s>

**UPD**. As @MichaelZajac notes, there is no mention of anonymous class in the AST of the snippet (https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3e00495d23a70a4ae1e00d77a8a6ee53/20f89ada3f279e5c26ff776334853b2be2e38d3f)

So now I believe that @AlexeyRomanov chose the right approach by trying to explain this from the parser's POV, but I've got a complete explanation of this:

First, note this:

> The most general form of class definition is `class cc[tps] as m(ps_1)…(ps_n) extends t`, `(n≥0)(n≥0)`.

Next, this:

> *t* is a template of the form `sc with mt_1 with … with mt_m { stats } // m≥0`

And, finally, this:

> The extends clause `extends sc with mt_1 with … with mt_m` can be omitted, in which case `extends scala.AnyRef` is assumed.

So, I think, we've got an `object A extends <template>`, where `<template>` is left with `extends` omitted, so only a `{stats}` block is present.

Comment: This makes sense to me that it treats `extends {}` as `extends <anonymous class that extends AnyRef>`, as `class Whatever extends ` won't work, you must have at least `{}` after extends

Comment: Then why does `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify { object A extends { val b = 123 } }` yield `object A extends AnyRef { val b = 123 }` ? If it were an anonymous class, you would see something like `final class $anon extends AnyRef`

Comment: @MichaelZajac nice catch! I've just read me some SLS, check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is normally used for [early definitions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions). <s>I believe that, strictly speaking, by specification it should be illegal: defining `object`s or `class`es isn't allowed there, and</s>

> Every early definition must define at least one variable.

However, in this case it's legal because `ClassDef` ends in `ClassTemplateOpt`, which is defined as

```
ClassTemplateOpt  ::=  `extends' ClassTemplate | [[`extends'] TemplateBody]
```

and `{ ... }` is `TemplateBody`, i.e. the body of the class (similarly for traits). The specification doesn't say why `extends` before `TemplateBody` is allowed, but it is.

Comment: At first I thought it's an early definition as well, but I don't believe it's the case any more. The spec (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions) clearly states that early definition has to be followed by `with`. Otherwise, there is no need to 'early-define' anything. So this is just an anonymous class, I suppose. Would be nice to have someone's final say on this, though.

Comment: @tkroman That's why my answer originally said "And because there is no `with` afterwards, it becomes a class body instead of an early definition." However, see the edited version.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing in braces is like an in-place class definition, so there is a reason why it may follow extends, however weird it seems.